# What is the console setting for kernel early_printk in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, console, kernel-parameters

I am working on an embedded Linux (kernel-5.10.24), and I enabled the early_printk in kernel configuration to help my debugging kernel.

Normally, the kernel command line has set `console=ttyS0,115200 ....`, and I can see the early printk logs in kernel.

But today, I changed the command line to `console=ttyS1,115200 ....` by mistake, and I assumed I would NOT see any kernel logs during kernel bootup.

And to my surprise, I can still see the first part of kernel log done by early printk, there is NO other logs afterwards.

So my question is how early printk output kernel logs to the `right` console, even the `console=` is set to a non-existing device (or wrong serial console) ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the value given to the console boot parameter, I will assume that your terminal is connected to the system via some serial line.

> how early printk output kernel logs to the right console, even the
> console= is set to a non-existing device

The reason for this is simply that… the terminal early boot messages will be output on some terminal irrespective of the ***console*** boot parameter value but determined by the ***[earlyprintk](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re05.html)*** boot parameter instead.

The *console* boot parmater only determines the "real" console. v.g. the terminal that will be used as console once standard linux drivers correctly initialized that is to say around the beginning of the init phase.
If you get this setting wrong then, logically, nothing will ever get output on the system console passed boot time.

> What is the console setting for kernel early_printk in Linux?

As you can read from *[The kernel’s command-line parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?highlight=earlyprintk)* :

> earlyprintk=vga
> earlyprintk=sclp
> earlyprintk=xen
> earlyprintk=serial[,ttySn[,baudrate]]
> earlyprintk=serial[,0x...[,baudrate]]
> earlyprintk=ttySn[,baudrate]
> earlyprintk=dbgp[debugController#]
> earlyprintk=pciserial[,force],bus:device.function[,baudrate]
> earlyprintk=xdbc[xhciController#]
>
> earlyprintk is useful when the kernel crashes before the normal
> console is initialized. It is not enabled by default because it has
> some cosmetic problems.
>
> Append ",keep" to not disable it when the real console takes over.
>
> Only one of vga, efi, serial, or usb debug port can be used at a time.
>
> Currently only ttyS0 and ttyS1 may be specified by name.  Other I/O
> ports may be explicitly specified on some architectures (x86 and arm
> at least) by replacing ttySn with an I/O port address, like this:
> earlyprintk=serial,0x1008,115200 You can find the port for a given
> device in /proc/tty/driver/serial: 2: uart:ST16650V2 port:00001008
> irq:18 ...
>
> Interaction with the standard serial driver is not very good.
>
> The VGA and EFI output is eventually overwritten by the real console.
>
> The xen output can only be used by Xen PV guests.
>
> The sclp output can only be used on s390.
>
> The optional "force" to "pciserial" enables use of a PCI device even
> when its classcode is not of the UART class.

Comment: I checked the bootloader settings, and did NOT find the `earlyprintk` defined. I am still confused, if `console=null` and no `earlyprink` configured, why kernel earlyprintk codes can print early logs to the serial console??